# PostgreSQL - Extract the maximum timestamp less than a certain date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, extract

I have a problem trying to query a task. So, I need to implement a Rating System for a contest platform, but to calculate and update a user's rating I need to extract the last rating a user had (because the table keeps the entire history).

Now, these are the tables responsible for this task (I left only the relevant columns):

store contests based on "ID":

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contests (
    id TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

stores all users who register for a particular contest:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contest_participants (
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    contest_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (username, contest_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (contest_id) REFERENCES contests (id)
);
```

stores the rating of all users based on the contests they have participated in:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contest_ratings (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    contest_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    username TEXT NOT NULL,
    rating INT NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (contest_id) REFERENCES contests (id)
);
```

Now, due to the ability to calculate more than 1 contest rating at a time, I can't use the `id` column in `contest_ratings` because that can create certain race conditions.

The best option I could find was to use the `date_end` column in `contests`. Basically, if I look for the maximum `data_end` that is lower than the current contest (ex: `max(date_end) < 'current_timestamp'`), I can find the last rating of a user. But I really can't figure out how to do that.

Let's say that we have the following data:

```
--------------------------------------|
             contests                 |
----------------+---------------------|
       id       |     date_end        |
----------------+------------------+--|
 test-contest-1 | 2022-05-10 15:55:00 |
 test-contest-2 | 2022-05-10 17:00:00 |
 test-contest-3 | 2022-05-12 17:09:00 | 

-----------------------------|
      contest_participants   |
------------+----------------|
  username  |   contest_id   |  
------------+----------------|
 KeepCoding | test-contest-1 |
 TestUser   | test-contest-1 | 
 KeepCoding | test-contest-2 |
 KeepCoding | test-contest-3 |
 TestUser   | test-contest-3 |

-------------------------------------------|
                contest_ratings            |
----+----------------+------------+--------|
 id |   contest_id   |  username  | rating |
----+----------------+------------+--------|
 1  | test-contest-1 | KeepCoding |    100 |
 2  | test-contest-1 | TestUser   |     10 |
 3  | test-contest-2 | KeepCoding |    200 |
```

And we want to calculate the rating for the `test-contest-3` contest. For that, we need to extract the rating from the `test-contest-2` contest for the `KeepCoding` user and the rating from `test-contest-1` for the `TestUser` user.

Trying to solve this by myself, this is pretty much all I could come up with but is not working properly, because is returning more `rating` columns for the same user and I just can't figure out why.

So first we want the maximum `date_end`:

```sql
SELECT id, max(date_end) as date_end FROM contests WHERE date_end < 'current_timestamp'
```

Then we extract the ratings

```sql
SELECT cr.username, cr.rating FROM (...) s JOIN contest_ratings cr ON s.id = cr.id
```

Then add the filter

```sql
SELECT * FROM (...) t JOIN contest_participants cp ON t.username = cp.username AND cp.contest = 'current-contest-id';
```

Where I wrote (...) I mean the previous query in parentheses

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Sure, I edited the post and added some sample data :)